# Using scipy routines outside of the GIL

Tags: python, scipy, cython, shared-memory, python-multithreading

This is sort of a general question related to a specific implementation I have in mind, about whether it's safe to use python routines designed for use inside the GIL in a shared memory environment. Specifically what I'd like to do is use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` on a large array inside a `cython` function.

The data can be expressed as a 2d `numpy` array (say, of floats) with the axis to be fit along and the other the serialized axis to be parallelized over. Then I'd just like to release the GIL and start looping through the data with a `cython.parallel.prange` (the idea being then that I can have all my cores working on fitting at once).

The main issue I can foresee is that `curve_fit` does not operate "in place"; it returns the fit values of the parameters (and optionally their covariance matrix) and so has to allocate that memory at some point. (Of course I also have no idea about any intermediate memory allocation the routine performs.) I'm worried about how this will operate outside the GIL with many threads working concurrently.

I realize that the answer could just be "it should work fine go try it," but I'm hoping to get some idea of what to look out for. I also realize that this question is similar to others about parallelizing `scipy`/`numpy` routines, but I think this one is worded differently in that falls within the `cython` scope of a C environment for python.

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Some compiled `numpy` and `scipy` code has code blocks marked with a `no gil` macro.  I'd suggest studying the `curve_fit` code.  It may be a mix of python and compiled code, maybe even a call to an outside library.

Comment: To add to @hpaulj's comment: if the scipy code does release the GIL internally then you'll get some benefit from the parallel loop without having to release the GIL yourself. _However_  if it's returning Python objects be careful, since it turns out Cython does not make them thread-local.

Comment: One more comment: `curve_fit` is likely to spend most of its time calling the user-supplied function (which will require the GIL) so the benefits are probably going to be small

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not safe. If CPython could safely run that kind of code without the GIL, we wouldn't have the GIL in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You may find the following discussion to be of interest on [Parallel Programming in SciPy](https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/ParallelProgramming).

[I would have posted this as merely a comment, but I lack the requisite reputation.]